# Не могу добавить элемент в массив в React через setState

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Нужно добавить имя в конец массива при нажатии на кнопку. Не могу найти ошибку.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {arr: ['Коля', 'Вася', 'Петя', 'Иван', 'Дима']};
    }

    addItem() {
        
        this.setState({arr: this.state.arr.push("Tom")});
    }

    
    render() {
        
        const list = this.state.arr.map((item, index) => {
            return <li key={index}>{item}</li>
        })
    
            
        
        return <div>
            <ul>{list}</ul>
            <button onClick={this.addItem}>Press me</button>
            </div>

    }
}
```

Comment: addItem() {
        
        this.setState({arr: [...this.state.arr, "Tom"])});
    }

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Забудь про классы, переходи на функциональное программирование с хуками

```
const App = () => {
    let [_state, setArray] = useState(['Коля', 'Вася', 'Петя', 'Иван', 'Дима']);

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    _state.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)
                }
            </ul>

            <button onClick={() => setArray([..._state, 'Tom'])}>Press me</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать.